# iCloud incremental data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

[Reading the iCloud design docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2-SW1), it mentions:

> Because the system tracks changes to the document, it is able to
>   upload only the parts that changed, as shown in step 2. This
>   optimization reduces iCloud network traffic and also reduces the
>   amount of power consumed by the device—important for battery-based
>   devices.

In my scenario, I have a plist file that a `UIDocument` tracks. What if I replace the plist file with a copy of same plist, same filename, same path? I know that the metadata gets updated, but does the entire file get transferred over to iCloud again?

Comment: If you replaced the file with one of the same name a path (which is technically what saving is), then iCloud would see it as an update and save the whole thing because technically, that's what has changed, but would call it a "changed part"

Comment: So even if the contents are exactly the same, iCloud will still upload the entire file?

Comment: You replaced the file with one of equivalent value and file name, but it's still a change to the document.  It's either that or the versioning system detects a different UID and erases the history of the previous version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud does not track based on UID, it tracks on filename.  Your file will be diffed and only the changes will be sent to iCloud.

If you want UID tracking, Apple recommends that you add a UID and document schema version to your file formats (as they do).