# iOS: using iCloud document storage for a small XML based database

Tags: ios, xml, document, icloud

Just wanted to know if this is a good idea:

I want to use iCloud to sync data between different devices in my iOS app. It's just a list of small objects without connections. But storing this list in the key/value store won't work because it's space is restricted to 1 MB or so and the list might get bigger (not much, but could...). Core data seems like an overkill to me and there is also the problem of possible duplicates.

So I wonder if it makes sense to subclass UIDocument to handle the XML file. Every object has an ID, so merging different versions of the file should be no problem.

Comment: It depends on the format of the data store (monolithic or transactions) and the volume of updates.  If the entire file (1 MB+) is constantly being written to by your app (and hence sync'ed to iCloud) or if a small change causes the entire store to be sync'ed to iCloud then I would use Core Data.  The advantage of core data is that only the transaction logs you require (or have changed) are synced.

Comment: Ok thanks, that helped a lot. Don't you want to put this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of XML depends on the format of the data store (monolithic or transactions) and the volume of updates. If the entire file (1 MB+) is constantly being written to by your app (and hence sync'ed to iCloud) or if a small change causes the entire store to be sync'ed to iCloud then I would use Core Data. The advantage of core data is that only the transaction logs you require (or have changed) are synced.

Comment: _"If the entire file (1 MB+) is constantly being written to by your app (and hence sync'ed to iCloud) or if a small change causes the entire store to be sync'ed to iCloud then I would use Core Data."_  [This is incorrect.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894108/icloud-incremental-data) iCloud document sync is also incremental.

Comment: @StCredZero: You don't appear to have understood my answer.  I am recommending Core Data because IT DOESN'T SYNC THE ENTIRE DATA STORE.  As per my last sentence (which you don't seem to have read): `The advantage of core data is that only the transaction logs you require (or have changed) are synced.`